# Demo a database mirroring on SQL Server, which choice is the best?

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, virtualization, high-availability

I'm going to demo a high-availability SQL Server database to my mentor. My current PC configurations are:

Pentium E6300

2G of RAM

Windows 7 Ultimate

I planned to create 3 virtual machines by Microsoft Virtual PC, all of them install Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard and SQL Server 2005 Enterprise SP3 to be the Server Role, Mirror Role and Witness Role. I thought that it'll work, but I doubt there are better solutions for me to create a demo system:

- Using only 3 instances of SQL Server (without Virtual machine and, of course, without Windows Server) run directly on my machine.
- Another ways that I've not known yet.

My question is:
- Which choice is the simplest?
- Which choice is the best demonstration for the abilities of database mirroring?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It makes the best demo to use different VMs for each instance. This shows that the connection moves from server to server instead of just between instances.